# Show Folders on Desktop Like KDE?

Tags: windows-7, desktop, kde, kubuntu

Is there a way to show folders on the desktop in Windows 7 like in KDE?

[image]

Comment: Everyone has different tastes. When I see this kind of thing in KDE, I close it as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [**Stardock Fences**](http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/screenshots.asp) is the program you need:

[image]